# Create React App - loading i18n translations from relative path

Tags: create-react-app, react-i18next, i18next-http-backend

My React app loads from a relative path by setting the `homepage` variable in package.json. However i18next-http-backend still tries to load the translations from `http://localhost:3000/locales/en/translation.json` instead of `http://localhost:3000/myapp/locales/en/translation.json`. I even tried setting the loadPath option (not sure of the syntax though), but that didn't work. Please see below:

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    loadPath: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
  })
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: is your locales folder under public folder?

Comment: Yes. The translation file is located here: `/public/locales/en/translation.json`

Comment: loadPath should be under backend object.
I mean you have to have something like this
{debug: true, backend: {loadPath: ""}} in your init

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `loadPath` needs to be set as part of the initialisation of the `Backend`, so you need to do the following...

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    backend: {
        loadPath: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`,
    }
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
  })
```

Comment: You just made my day :-)